# Way to convert this to LINQ conditionals

Tags: c#, linq

I need to select or remove numbers that are in list (0-24)

```
            if (numberList.Contains(int.Parse(c[0])))
            {
                numberList.Remove(int.Parse(c[0]));
            }

            if (int.Parse(c[1] + (a.Info[i].Dydis / a.Greitis)) >= 60)
            {
                int v = int.Parse(c[0]) + 1;
                if (numberList.Contains(v)) 
                    numberList.Remove(v);
            }

            if ((rez(a.Info[i].Dydis, a.Greitis)) > 1)
            {
                numberList.Add(99);
            }

        }
        if (numberList.Count != 0)
        {
            Ats k = new Ats(a.Vardas, a.Data, numberList);
            nera.Add(k);
        }
```

I'm trying something like this, but it isn't working :

```
        for (int i = 0; i < a.LCount; i++)
        {
            string[] c = a.Info[i].Laikas.Split(':'); 
            var q = from d in numberList
                    where (numberList.Contains(int.Parse(c[0])))
                    select new
                    {
                        Number = int.Parse(c[0]),
                    };
```

How could I convert this thing to a LINQ?

Comment: What's an input data? You have to provide more details, if you want to get an answer.

Comment: Don´t convert to LINQ for the sake of "converting to LINQ". Instead *know* what you´re doing. Your code seems quite clear to me the way you already have, why want to obfuscate it with messy, complicated linq-statement? Furthermore: what does "isn´t working" mean? What do you expect? What do you get instead?

Comment: I need it for the uni.. Input data is hours when data is received, and I need to select the hours when data was(or wasn't transferred)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var exc = c.Select(int.Parse);
var q = numberList.Where(_ => !exc.Contains(_)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that by using lambda expression:

```
numberList.RemoveAll( item => exlist.Contains(item));
```

**exlist** will contain 0-24 integers. Or,

```
numberList.RemoveAll(item => item  >= 0 && item <= 24);
```